# Backbone.js - Other frameworks that provide Collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, spine.js, sammy.js

I am inclined to BackboneJs for mvc structuring javascript files now. I am quite happy with the current setup and i would like to now improve my knowledge of other javascript frameworks available that is tiny in it's core like Backbonejs, provides collection to manage array of models like Bb does. I tried `SpineJs`, `SammyJs` with simple app but i think they are quite lacking something which i am unable to identify currently. Which other frameworks have i got at my disposal, also is there a way to emulate collections in either of the above said libraries.

Comment: @Tomasz any reason to close the question. I would love to know :) also i would delete it it reasoning is valid

Comment: I haven't voted to close it, I only [slightly corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8972815/revisions) the title. You question is fine as far as I am concerned. I think only moderators know who voted before the question is actually closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question deserve a 4 pages answer....

to make it short:

1. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)  for a plethora of others frameworks
   review. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102215/mvp-pattern-with-javascript-framework) is a good place to have a look
2. please
   specify some more of your rquirements (ok for handling of
   collections). For instance, backbone.js is great when used with
   restful DBs like couchdb (really, a 5 minutes work, I use it--)
3. some months ago, when I had to decide which framework to choose for
   my app, I was in your same situation. I had to choose among
   angularjs, knockout, and backbone.js    The choice falled on
   backbone.js and I never regretted it.

hope this helps.
bye.

Answer (score 0):

[TaffyDB](http://taffydb.com/) is the closest that I can think in dealing with collection of js objects. It has a database - like api in dealing with js objects. However, you have to

- convert spinejs' to json before inserting to taffy db
- taffyDB does not provide way to synchronize data to server

It seems too much of a work, though I've suggested it in case it may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

[Models](http://spinejs.com/docs/models) in SpineJS have some basic *Collection* functionality.
Check out the [Model Relationships guide](http://spinejs.com/docs/relations) on the SpineJS website.